# Multiple/Duplicate Rows By Unique Key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, using Apps Script, I have 3 sheets which I want to take the keys from sheet 1 and duplicate the rows from sheet 2 against them so that for every unique key, every value from sheet 2 populates. See sheet 3 as an example output. Notice how in sheet 1, the keys only appears once, but I need the keys to duplicate to match the number of rows from sheet 2.

Any ideas?

Sheet 1: Contains the unique keys

Sheet 2: Contains the values I wanted multiplied/duplicated

Sheet 3: Contains the desired output.

sheet 1 [image]

sheet 2[image]

sheet 3[image]

Comment: Show your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 cols from Sheet2, use this -

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  // read Key column, [ [value], [value], [value]... ]
  var v1 = s1.getRange(2, 1, s1.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  // flatten array of arrays into array, [value, value...]
  v1 = v1.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });
  // read 2 columns, [ [value1, value2], [value1, value2], [value1, value2]... ]
  var v2 = s2.getRange(2, 1, s2.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  // hold rows to insert, will become [row, row]
  var result = [];

  v1.forEach(function(k) {
    v2.forEach(function(v) {
      // create row as [k, v1, v2]
      // change needed here if Sheet3 row has to be combo of Sheet2 cols
      result.push([k].concat(v));
    });
  });

  // get range of required length and insert values into sheet
  // 2, which row to start, 1, which col to start, result.length, how many rows, 2, how many cols
  s3.getRange(2, 1, result.length, 3).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was overthinking this. Much simpler the way you did it.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the Key and Values columns and use the values to create writable rows for Sheet3. Below code shows a simple approach to do this inside a `test` function you can copy/paste and run.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  // read Key column, [ [value], [value], [value]... ]
  var v1 = s1.getRange(2, 1, s1.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  // flatten array of arrays into array, [value, value...]
  v1 = v1.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });
  // read Values column, [ [value], [value], [value]... ]
  var v2 = s2.getRange(2, 1, s2.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  // flatten array of arrays into array, [value, value...]
  v2 = v2.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });

  // hold rows to insert, will become [row, row]
  var result = [];

  v1.forEach(function(k) {
    v2.forEach(function(v) {
      // create row as [k, v]
      result.push([k, v]);
    });
  });

  // get range of required length and insert values into sheet
  // 2, which row to start, 1, which col to start, result.length, how many rows, 2, how many cols
  s3.getRange(2, 1, result.length, 2).setValues(result);
}
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `map`, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for `forEach`, [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for `SpreadsheetApp` and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) for `sheet`.

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: I am working to expand the code you provided to include additional columns from sheet 2. For example, I want to include columns 1 and 2 from sheet 2, rather than only column 1. However, I am finding this change is not as intuitive as I expected. I added the below code, then expanded the s3.gerRange to 3 columns. However, this is duplicating the results.     // read Values column, [ [value], [value], [value]... ]
  var v3 = s2.getRange(2, 1,  s2.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  // flatten array of arrays into array, [value, value...]
  v3 = v3.map(function(el) {
    return el[1];
  });

Comment: @bava Don't ask more questions in comments. If sufficient research and experimentation don't resolve an issue you're having, ask a new, specific question where your hard work can be properly conveyed. Asking in comments always makes it seem as though you didn't try very hard yourself (even if you did).